# Android Studio : Reset/Restore "Remember, don't ask again" .

Tags: android-studio

By pressing `CTRL`+`ALT`+`L` , a dialog box opens up which contains many options like `Reformat Code`, `Optimize Code`, etc.

I mistakenly enabled check for `Remember, don't ask again`. Now that dialog box is not opening up. I want that dialog box to show. I went through all the options in the `Settings` but no luck.

Somebody please help! TIA!